# Updating text with p5js

Tags: canvas, processing, p5.js

I am have text defined in my draw loop that is updated from a global variable.

```javascript
  function draw() {
    ...
    levelText = text("level: " + level, 120, 100);
    pointsText = text("points: " + points, 120, 150);
    ...

  }
```

The problem is that, when I update the variables *level* and *points*, the previous text drawings remain on the canvas and the updated versions are numbers crossed out with other numbers.  How can I erase the previous number from then canvas when it is updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call the [`background()`](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background) function to clear out old frames that you've drawn. Otherwise you're just drawing over what's already there. Something like this:

```javascript
function draw() {
    background(255, 0, 0); //draws a red background
    text("level: " + level, 120, 100);
    text("points: " + points, 120, 150);
 }
```

Also notice that I've removed your `levelText` and `pointsText` variables. I'm not sure what they were for, since the `text()` function returns `this`, which you're already in anyway.

If you don't want to draw the entire background, then you at least need to do something like fill a rectangle over the place where you're about to draw the text.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the `background()` function is an option. But why paint a color over old frames if you can just clear the canvas? Use [`clear()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/clear), please. That is exactly what the function was made for.

```javascript
function draw(){
  clear();
  // draw new stuff here
}
```